# Error: ng:areq Bad Argument: Argument 'registerController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular.I tried incuding a new controller for node.js api integration into my login page.But I was getting the above error.I have seen the related questions but was not able to solve my problem.Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

registerCtrl.js

```
 /*jslint node: true */
   /*jslint white: true */
  (function() {
 'use strict';

 angular.module('registerCtrl', [])  

 .controller('registerController', function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {

  var register = this;
  var method = 'POST';
  var inserturl = 'http://localhost:8080/v1/auth/login';// URL where the Node.js server is running
  $scope.codeStatus = "";
  $scope.save = function() {
    // Preparing the Json Data from the Angular Model to send in the Server. 
    var formData = {
      'email' : this.email,
      'password' : this.password
    };

    this.password = '';
    this.email = '';

    var jdata = 'mydata='+JSON.stringify(formData); // The data is to be string.

    $http({ // Accessing the Angular $http Service to send data via REST Communication to Node Server.
            method: method,
            url: inserturl,
            data:  jdata ,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            cache: $templateCache
        }).
        success(function(response) {
        console.log("success"); // Getting Success Response in Callback
                $scope.codeStatus = response.data;
        console.log($scope.codeStatus);

        }).
        error(function(response) {
        console.log("error"); // Getting Error Response in Callback
                $scope.codeStatus = response || "Request failed";
        console.log($scope.codeStatus);
        });
        return false;
  };    

});
}());
```

register.html

```
<div ng-controller="registerController as register">
<div class="container">    
    <div id="loginbox" ng-show="signin-value"  style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                    
        <div class="panel panel-info" >
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                    <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
                </div>     

                <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

                    <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                    <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="save()">

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                    <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="email" value="" placeholder="email">                                        
                                </div>

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                    <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                                </div>

                        <div class="input-group">
                                  <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                      <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>


                            <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                                <!-- Button -->

                                <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                  <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                        Don't have an account! 
                                    <a href="#" ng-click="login-value= false;signup-value=true;">
                                        Sign Up Here
                                    </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </form>     
                    </div>                     
                </div>  
    </div>
```

I have also added js file in index.html as

```
    <script src="app/controllers/registerCtrl.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does your `ng-app` attribute look like?

Comment: I difnt get you @phil

Comment: You should have an element in your HTML file with `ng-app="..."`. What does that look like?

Comment: in my index.html I ahave given  ng-app="app";

Comment: Ok, so where is your `app` module defined and does it add `registerCtrl` as a dependency? Ie, something like `angular.module('app', ['registerCtrl'])`

Comment: It adds appRoutes and appServices as dependencies,and in approutesI have written like this  .when('/register', {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/register.html',
                controller: 'registerController',
                controllerAs: 'register'

            })

Comment: So there's your problem; nothing is including the `registerCtrl` module as a dependency

Comment: Why are you using `ng-controller` if your controller is defined in a route configuration? You shouldn't be using both

Answer (score 1):

your `registerController` function hasn't been injected into an application controller:

```
registerCtrl.controller('registerController', registerController)
```

Also, in your template you have to use `ng-app` to declare where your application starts and your controllers need to be nested within, like this:

```
<div ng-app="registerCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="registerController">
```

One more thing, why have you named your application `registerCtrl`? It isn't a controller is it?

Lastly, your round brackets at the end are incorrectly ordered. Change to:

```
)();
```

from

```
());
```

Comment: registerCtrl is the js file name which I have given as module name itself.The controller is registerController which I have used in html file.

Comment: I haved  edited my question,and replaced my controller..still also getting the same error..:(

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it's clear that nothing in your app is including the `registerCtrl` module as a dependency therefore the `registerController` controller is not available to your application.

Seeing as the `registerController` controller is used in `appRoutes`, you should include the module dependency there. For example (and note this might not be exactly right)...

```
angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute', 'registerCtrl'])
```